# New Editing feature

Tags: discussion, support, edits, edit-badges

With the addition of the new free for all editing feature what happens with regards to earning the badges Strunk & White and Copy Editor

As I understand it, and correct me if I'm wrong, anyone can make an edit however if the person making the edit is below the reputation threshold for editing (2000 for Stack Overflow) then the edit needs to be approved by 2 people (who have reputation above the editing threshold?)

In terms of counting edits for the badges - who gets the edit?  Is it the person making the edit, the person approving the edit, both or neither?

Answer (score 2):

According the [query used](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5117/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white), it will be the person who made the edit.  If you approve an edit, you see that the recorded "edited" user is still the original editor.

That is, unless SE decides to change the way it is calculated.